# php Array map function

Tags: php, arrays

I am working on PHP Script and experienced a challenge as a below. My main Aim is to create a Select Query from my db, with different query operators. So far, I have this

```
public function select(array $columns, array $where)
    {
        $tableName = static::tableName();

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($where); $i++){
            $attributes[] = $where[$i][0];
            $operators[] = $where[$i][1];
        }

        $operator = implode(" ", array_map(fn($oper) => "$oper", $operators));
        $sql = implode(" AND ", array_map(fn($attr) => "$attr $operator :$attr", $attributes));
        $columns = implode(", ", array_map(fn($att) => "$att", $columns));
        $stmt = self::prepare("SELECT $columns FROM $tableName WHERE $sql ");

        .......
    }
```

`$where` contains an array of the Conditions with the column, operator and the value eg `[["id", ">", 3], ["firstname", "=", "John"]]`.

The sql query should be like

```
SELECT username, email 
FROM table_name WHERE id >  :id AND firstname  = :firstname
```

However, what I get is

```
SELECT username, email 
FROM table_name WHERE id >= :id AND firstname >= :firstname
```

which is incorrect. How can I match the operators correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the logic of [user3783243's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71273029/8726713), in addition to that of the question itself. Just change the dynamic creation of the conditions to be able to use them in the array_map.

```
function select (array $columns, array $where) {
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($where); $i++){
    $conditions[] = $where[$i][0] . ' ' . $where[$i][1] . ' :' . $where[$i][0];
    $params[] = $where[$i][2];
  }
  $sql = implode(" AND ", array_map(fn($cond) => "$cond", $conditions));
  $columns = implode(", ",array_map(fn($att) => "$att",$columns));
  echo "SELECT $columns FROM ".tableName()." WHERE $sql";
}
```

Also pass `$params` to the `execute` method.

The full example [here](https://3v4l.org/aEsZi)

Answer (score 1):

I would not use `array_map`. I would use a `foreach` and just build the query dynamically:

```
$where = [["id", ">", 3], ["firstname", "=", "John"]];
$wherequery = ' where ';
foreach($where as $w){
    $wherequery .= $w[0] . ' ' . $w[1] . ' ? ';
    $params[] = $w[2];
}
echo "SELECT columns FROM table " . $wherequery;
```

then just pass `$params` to the `execute` method.

https://3v4l.org/k8F2Y

alternatively with named placeholders:

```
$where = [["id", ">", 3], ["firstname", "=", "John"]];
$wherequery = ' where';
foreach($where as $w){
    $wherequery .= ' ' . $w[0] . ' ' . $w[1] . ' :' . $w[0];
    $params[$w[0]] = $w[2];
}
echo "SELECT columns FROM table " . $wherequery;
```

https://3v4l.org/5WXK5

Comment: Yes, this is it. But it misses AND in the WHERE Condition. @Matias has solved i. Thank you all.